# How to correctly stop a service when all the threads are done

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I have a service that fires a new network thread every time the onStartCommand is called.
When the last thread finishes, I have to stop the service.

Is there any good practice to handle this? Right now I have a HashTable in the service and I add and remove a token when the thread starts/finishes.

Every time a thread finishes it removes the token from the hashTable and if the hashtable is empty then I stop the service. This works but I know it is not 100% safe because an old thread can be checking for the size of the hashtable right before a new thread is inserting its token to the hashtable and, therefore, stoping the service when there's actually a new thread starting.

Comment: consider extending `IntentService`. That handles threads and stopping. Or have a look at the [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/IntentService.java) of that

Comment: I cannot. I need to use classic services.

Comment: IntentServices handles calls one at a time. I need multithreading.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mutex protect the access to the hashTable, something like this:
(Assuming pthreads and c++, you'll have to change that accordingly, but I think you get the idea)

```
int getHashTableSize()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&yourMutex);
    int size = yourHashTable.size();
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&yourMutex);

    return size;
}

void addThread(TokenType &token)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&yourMutex);
    yourHashTable.addToken(token);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&yourMutex);
}

void removeThread(TokenType &token)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&yourMutex);
    yourHashTable.removeToken(token);
    // check if yourHashTable is empty here, and stop service accordingly
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&yourMutex);
}

onStartCommand()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&yourMutex);
    // Logic for wake lock, thread creation, and adding to the hash table here
    // possibly need to consider recursive mutex locking
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&yourMutex);
}
```

Of course you'll have to change the types accordingly and add these methods to the appropriate class.

Another common practice is to wait for the threads to complete by calling join, as follows. This of course is only useful if the number of threads is "static". If you have an application where thread creation is dynamic, then this second approach may not be as useful.

```
for(int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
{
    // threadIds is a vector
    pthread_join(threadIds[i], NULL);
}
// At this point, all of your threads are complete
```

Comment: Actually I don't think you need the mutex because HashTable is already synchronized, in Java.

Comment: @HéctorJúdezSapena, even though the HashTable operations are synchronized, you need to extend the scope of the locking. That is, make all of the logic in removeThread() atomic. So I would suggest switching to a container that is not synchronized, and manage the scope of the synchronization yourself.

Comment: However this also doesn't solve the problem. When onStartCommand is called I first run some lines of code to get a wake lock before I add the token to the hashtable. During the execution of these lines of code the service has still not created the new Thread and if there's another thread checking for the size of the table the size will be 0, therefore stoping the service.

Comment: @HéctorJúdezSapena, sounds like you'll need to use the same mutex in that method as well. I added some extra code for that to my answer.

Comment: This will help a little bit but it will not solve the problem 100% because onStartCommand gets called by the system when I want to start the service. Between startService(Intent) and onStartCommand the system also executes code and during this time there can be another old thread checking the hashtable. Maybe I have to add the token to a static table before I exectute startService()..

Comment: but now that I think, you are right. I don't think onStartCommand will be executed if the service has been stoped.. therefore adding a mutex in onStartCommand will probably work.

Comment: @HéctorJúdezSapena, ya, I was just about to reply to your previous comment. Basically I dont see any other way around it. You're going to have to manage the synchronization yourself, making these different pieces of logic atomic.

Comment: based on your comments http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303027/can-a-callback-method-that-runs-in-the-main-thread-run-in-the-middle-of-onstartc I will not need to synchronize anything because all the access to the HashTable are done in the main thread.

Comment: @HéctorJúdezSapena, its hard to tell since I would have to see all of the code. But it sounds like you dont want synchronization in the actual hash table methods, but at a higher level. And if there will be related logic both in the main thread and the spawned threads, then some sort of synchronization will be needed.